# What are the OpenSSH ciphers default rekey transmission limit values?

Tags: encryption, openssh

The OpenSSH `sshd_config` man page says for `RekeyLimit`s first argument:

> Specifies the maximum amount of data that may be transmitted before the session key is renegotiated [...]
> The default is between ‘1G’ and ‘4G’, depending on the cipher.

Where can I see each cipher's default rekey transmission limit, e.g. in my case the limits of `aes128-ctr` and `aes128-cbc` ?